# Type mismatch: cannot convert from JavaRDD<Object> to JavaRDD<String>

Tags: java, apache-spark

I just started learning Apache Spark and doing a project. The first task is reading a file contains multiple lines of text and get a dictionary. Based on my understanding I write the following code:

```
JavaRDD<String> lines = spark.sparkContext().textFile("tokens.txt",10).toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<String> dictionary = lines.flatMap(l -> l.split(" "));
```

I also tried

```
JavaRDD<String> dictionary = lines.flatMap(l -> Arrays.asList(l.split(" ")));
```

However Eclipse is giving me this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from JavaRDD<Object> to
>   JavaRDD<String>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would `l -> l.split(" ")` be a valid argument for `flatMap()`?

Comment: @shmosel I don't know why since I am new to Spark, what should be the correct argument?

Comment: It depends on the version. But you don't need me to tell you. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. Need to call iterator() at the end.

```
JavaRDD<String> dictionary = lines.flatMap(l -> Arrays.asList(l.split(" ")).iterator());
```